# Getting data from Laravel Api to Vue Page

Tags: vuejs2, axios, laravel-5.7

I'm a beginner in vue.js and I'm trying to get an api result and show it to my vue page. my Api is built with Laravel 5.7.
I've just installed Vue axios package to work with http.

Here is my code:

TaskController

```
 public function index()
 {
    return response(Task::all()->jsonSerialize(), Response::HTTP_OK);
 }
```

App.vue

```
<template>
<div class="app-component">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Task Title</th>
                <th>Priority</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <task-component v-for="task in tasks" :key="task.id" :task="task"></task-component>
           <tr>
               <td><input type="text" id="task" class="form-control"></td>
               <td>
                   <select id="select" class="form-control">
                       <option>Low</option>
                       <option>Medium</option>
                       <option>High</option>
                   </select>
                </td>
                <td><button class="btn btn-primary">Add</button></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import TaskComponent from './Task.vue';
export default{
    data(){
        return{
                tasks: [],
        }
    },

    methods: {
        getTasks(){
            window.axios.get('/api/tasks').then(({data})=>{
                data.forEach(task =>{
                this.tasks.push(task)
            });
          });
        },
        created(){
            this.getTasks();
        }
    },
    components:{TaskComponent}
}
</script>
```

Task Page

```
<template>
     <tr>
        <td>{{ task.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ task.priority }}</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button></td>
    </tr>
</template>
<script>
export default{
    data(){
        return{
        }
    },
    props: ['task']
}   

</script>
```

I got no errors but no result appeared to my vue although the controller returns json data correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the created() hook should not be in methods:

```
export default {
   methods: {},
   created() {}
}
```